# C# MVC EntityState many to many delete and update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, many-to-many

I don't have much expirience with C# MVC EntityState, I usually work with IT infraestructure, but I started to create a new program and I need help to solve this problem.

I have this database:
Professional        Company
ID                  ID
Name                Descrition
...

A professional can work in one or more companies and a company can have one or more professional.

My ProfessionalController.cs code:

```
   public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,...")] Profissional profissional, List<int> companiesList)
   {

       if (ModelState.IsValid){

           if (companiesList != null){
               List<Companies> lista = new List<Companies>();
               foreach (int ID in companiesList)
                {
                    lista.Add(db.Companies.Find(ID));
                }

               var profissionalN = db.Profissional.Find(profissional.ID);
               var needDelete = profissionalc.Companies.Except(lista).ToList();
               var needCreate = lista.Except(profissionalc.Companies).ToList();

               profissional.Companies.Clear();
               db.Entry(profissionalN).State = EntityState.Detached;
               db.Entry(profissional).State = EntityState.Modified;

               foreach (Companies convenio in needCreate){
                   profissional.Companies.Add(convenio);
               }
               foreach (Companies convenio in needDelete){
                   profissional.Companies.Remove(convenio);
               }
           }

           db.Entry(profissional).State = EntityState.Modified;
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");

       }
       return View(profissional);
   }
```

I can add professionals to companies, but I can't delete.

Can anyone help-me?

I also tried the code below to delete, whitout sucess:

```
    public void RemoveCompanies(int profissionalID, int companyID)
    {
        var profissional2 = db.Profissional.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == profissionalID);
        var company2 = db.Company.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == companyID);
        profissional2.Company.Remove(companyID);
        db.Entry(profissional2).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You detached the 'profissional' variable from the context. Cascade delete directives and referential constraints in an identifying relationship are not enforced during a detach operation. I.e. the companies which you removed will not be enforced as the 'profissional' variable was detached at the time.

Try removing the `db.Entry(profissionalN).State = EntityState.Detached;` line.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
This is another variable professionalN not profesisonal, I know their names are similar...
Without this I have 2 objets professional and a error.

I can update in cascade, but can't delete.
This is another instance of professional.

Comment: @PabloRogerioFagundes Indeed it is a different name, but you are using profissionalN = db.Profissional.Find(profissional.ID). Therefore profissionalN.ID = profissional.ID. You are detaching the entity with that ID. You can also try using db.Professional.Attach(profissional) before you set the entry state to Modified and save changes. But I believe the issue is that you are trying to remove companies from a detached entity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.
I removed the `db.Entry(profissionalN).State = EntityState.Detached`
And added the code `db.Entry(profissional).Collection(x => x.Company).Load();`